# How to override default styles in Grommet?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, grommet

I have a grommet JS project in which I am using a LoginForm component.

I have gone through the component's help page and can see the functionality that it provides. Here is the reference:

https://grommet.github.io/docs/login-form

But, What if I have a custom requirement? Say, to make the login button disabled until both username and password are entered? How do I then get a reference to that button and the text fields there?

Is it even allowed to do this according to Grommet methodologies?

Answer (score 0):

I dont think it is very recommendable to override styles as the framework is for that, it provides with a lot of options but all of them according the harmony of the framework, checkout the [button's examples](https://grommet.github.io/docs/button/examples)

Also if you want that disabled it is enough to do not provide an onClick property or put it as falsy value:

```
<Button label='submit'  onClick={null} />
```

However yes there are special cases where you want to put your own styles so you can do something like:

```
<Button label='submit' style={{ marginRight: 2, marginLeft: 2 }} />
```

As you can see the style is not a string but an object, more info in [inline styles | React](http://reactjs.cn/react/tips/inline-styles.html)

Comment: Hi Marco. Thanks for the answer. Thing is, in the LoginForm component that I am talking about, we do not even have access to the submit button so that I can apply styles to that as specified by you. What is to be done in such a case?

Comment: Ho I see, the LoginForm is a composed component so in this case you should do the Form from scratch, there you can set the styles to each component.

Comment: Some thing like this [codepen](http://codepen.io/MarcoMedrano/pen/vmamxR?editors=0010)

Answer (score 0):

Grommet provides a mechanism to manage the theme so it fits your plans.
There are a lot of things that can be changed by creating a custom theme, look at my answer here:
[Grommet UI -- Custom Color Schemes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38272509/grommet-ui-custom-color-schemes)
Once you did it, *your styles* are the default styles.  \
it's not only the colors, many other things can be tuned.