# Grommet - border radius; can it be adjusted globally?

Tags: grommet

Grommet looks interesting. Not sure I'm in love with button border radius; is there a theme way to reset button radius on all Grommet buttons globally?

Answer (score 0):

The border radius is (mostly) managed by the active theme.
And the theme is (mostly) managed by you.
Check my answer to this question: [Grommet UI -- Custom Color Schemes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38272509/grommet-ui-custom-color-schemes)
It sets border radius somewhere.
You might need to do it for different controls.

Answer (score 0):

For each type of Button you are using you can set `border: undefined` on your theme, using the following structure:

```
const customTheme = {
  button: {
    default: {
      border: undefined,
    },
    primary: {
      background: {
        color: 'brand',
      },
      border: undefined,
    },
  },
};
```

In this example, the default Button and the primary Button will have no border, and that could work for any other type of Button you are interested in using.